Firebase Cloud Function : Trigger function timeout when many instances are created at once
I have noticed that cloud functions that runs on Cloud Storage object creation, timeout with no details in the log as to why after a certain amount of instances created.
In my case, I add 900 objects on which there is a onCreate trigger set up.
After I noticed the issue, I added console.time around main parts of the process and noticed that the part that handles creating an object in Cloud Storage takes more and more time as the number of instances increase.
First instances take around 1s, then few instances later it takes 2, then 5s then 15s then all following instances timeout.
There is already a similar question but didn't receive an answer. I see the same logs as in this previous question.
I believe this issue has to do with some sort of limit on google storage side but I can't find anything that explains this behaviour.
There are about 20 to 25 new instances created per second.
In the screenshots below, you can see how process time increases as the number of instances increase
Can someone advise what's going on ?




    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import {get} from './httpclient';
    import {updateDoc} from './firestore-helper';
    import {getPdfContentFromStatement} from './pdf-tools';
 
     export const onCompanyWalletStatementAdded = functions
      .runWith({
        vpcConnector: 'vpc-connector-value',
        vpcConnectorEgressSettings: 'ALL_TRAFFIC'
      })
      .region('europe-west1')
      .firestore
      .document(`somepath/{someId}`)
      .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
       const statement = snap.data();
     const wallet = await get(`api-url/${statement.walletId}`, {});
   // This api call, requires the call to originate from a given IP
   // Otherwise, it may cause timeout
     // this following line create an object that is used by pdfmake
       const pdf = getPdfContentFromStatement();
       const pdfmake = require('pdfmake');
          const printer = new pdfmake(fonts);
          const options = {tableLayouts};
          const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdf, options);
          const str = admin.storage();
          const bucket = str.bucket(`${storageBucket}`);
          const myPdfFile = bucket.file(`${gcsPath}/${fileName}`);
        
          const prom = new Promise<string>(
            (resolve, reject) => {
              pdfDoc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream())
              .on('finish',  () => {
                resolve('OK');
              })
              .on('error', (err: any) => {
                reject(err);
              });
              pdfDoc.end();
            }
          );
          const status = await prom;
          if (status === 'OK') {
            await myPdfFile.makePublic();
            const url = await myPdfFile.publicUrl();
            statement.url = url;
            await updateDoc(`somepath/${someId}`, statement);
          }
          return null;
    })


Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy what you have and follow your instructions to observe the same result.

The code works. it's only after certain number of instances that the function times out. I will update the question with the part the part that I suspect causes the timeout.

Well, to be honest, the code doesn't work the way you expect (otherwise you wouldn't be posting!).  We need to see if you might be doing something wrong that could only become a problem at scale.

Your code is incomplete - it can't be copied and run independently.  A few things: 1) There is no exported function that defines its entrypoint - we don't know where execution begins, or how you deploy it.  2) We can't see what admin is. Please edit the question to provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example that anyone can copy and run with your instructions.

You should also add some logging in your code to figure out if the function is terminating the way you expect.  Timeouts often occur as a result of promises that never resolve or reject, so you need to be absolutely certain that all of your promises are resolving in all cases, and if not, which one is holding up the progress of your code.

I have logs before and after this piece of code but the logs only show timeout for each instance (see the last screenshot)

As I was editing my question to add more details, I figured out the timeout might be cause by the vpc connector not working properly after a certain amount of traffic. I do make a call to an api that whitelists IPs that are allowed to communicate with it. I remember now that when I forgot to add the runWith vpcConnector in an other story, I have had timeout issues. Now, is it possible that as things scale, the vpc connector drops ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No idea.  You should edit the question to add all relevant information, including anything you got during debugging.

Turns out the problem was caused by the vpc connector. When I set it up, I chose min 2 and max 3 instances.
The trigger function in hand uses the vpc connector which works fine until it hits the vpc connector maximum bandwidth. At which point, I assume, GCP uses its normal network to handle the following outgoing traffic.
The api I talk to needs to recognize my IP, when it doesn't it never responds which causes the timeout.
Problem is, once you set up a vpc connector, you can no longer change the max number of instances. Creating a new one and using it instead might break things in production.
My solution to this problem will be to streamline this process instead of bulking in one batch.commit
Hope this will help others, and that Google will find a way to make it possible de update a vpc connector min/max instances
